# Separate these into as many equations as possible using Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

$x = 45 \mod 18$

$x = c^d \mod n^2m$ for gcd$(n,m) = 1$

I'm not really sure how we can tell how many equations it's possible to split these into. Moreover, I'm not even sure how to split them into separate equations. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a bit of an odd question and I'm not sure if this is an answer but here goes.

The basic Chinese Remainder Theorem (slightly simplified for the purposes of exposition) works like this: if you have a system of two simultaneous congruences
$$x\equiv b_1\pmod{m_1}\quad\hbox{and}\quad x\equiv b_2\pmod{m_2}\ ,$$
where $m_1$ and $m_2$ are relatively prime, then the system is equivalent to a single congruence
$$x\equiv\{\hbox{something}\}\pmod{m_1m_2}\ .$$

In fact, however, the converse of this is also true: if you have a congruence modulo $m_1m_2$, where $m_1$ and $m_2$ are relatively prime, it can be split into two congruences, modulo $m_1$ and $m_2$.  For example,
$$x\equiv17\pmod{52}$$
is equivalent to
$$x\equiv17\pmod{4}\quad\hbox{and}\quad x\equiv17\pmod{13}\ ,$$
which can then be simplified to
$$x\equiv1\pmod{4}\quad\hbox{and}\quad x\equiv4\pmod{13}\ .$$

I think perhaps this is what your question is asking.  As for why they put $c^d$ for one of the right hand sides - I have no idea!